# hide navigation bar throughout the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, uinavigationbar

I know using below statement I can hide navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

But I want to do this for whole app.

I don't want to write this statement in all files.

So any idea how can I hide navigation bar for whole project?

Comment: You only have to do it once per navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used Storyboards, then setting the Navigation Bar to None in the Navigation Controller, and ensuring that the top bar is set to 'Inferred' for all view controllers contained within the navigation controller will ensure that the navigation bar will be hidden for all view controllers in the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
    self.navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

Comment: read question again... what is the difference between your syntax and that I have in my question????